# Generic template argument in template function

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, pointers

I have a template class which has a -template- function that takes a pointer of the same class as the first argument, for example:

```
template<class T>
class Foo{
    void f(Foo* foo){}
}
```

When I use it in my main function, everything seems to be working until I use a different template for the argument.

```
int main(){
    Foo<double> f1;
    Foo<double> f2;
    f1.f(&f2); //No errors;

    Foo<bool> f3;
    f1.f(&f3);//Error : No matching function to call to Foo<double>::f(Foo<bool>*&)
}
```

Apparently, the only function defined here is `Foo<T>::f(Foo<T>*)`

Is there any way I can define `f` that takes a "generic" template `Foo` pointer so I can use it with any other type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the symbol `Foo` inside the definition of `Foo` itself is equivalent to saying `Foo<T>`. If you want to support any other instantiation of `Foo`, make `f` a template function:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
    template <class U>
    void f(Foo<U>* foo) { }
};
```

Comment: ok and if I want to have a pointer to another `Foo` object in my class that is not of type `T`?

Comment: @elirovi Use a base class, void, any, or don't.  You have an X/Y problem.

Comment: @Elirovi: That's a separate question.  Is this pointer going to be a member variable?  In that case Foo needs to derive from FooBase, and the pointer is to FooBase.  Is it a local variable? In that case, you need to make it a pointer whatever sort of Foo you are pointing at.

Comment: @MartinBonner Sorry, I'm kinda new to templates, can you guys give me an example?

Comment: @Elirovi: You need to ask a new question, explaining what the problem you are trying to solve is (not just "how do I get a pointer to a Foo<U>"), and show us an example of how you have tried to solve it so far.

Comment: @MartinBonner ok I'll be doing that right now! Thanks anyways